# Firestore - iOS Snapshot Listener Error - The referenced transaction has expired or is no longer valid

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Update - 13th January 2018**

In case anyone is still following this, it doesn't look like Firebase has fixed it yet.

As a work around, I've been checking to see if the error returned from the snapshot listener matches one of the two error messages mentioned below, and if so, I reattach the listener. Definitely not ideal, but at least it helps to guarantee my listeners haven't randomly expired when I'm expect them to be active.

Here's some sample code, which may help anyone still experiencing this issue:

```
class FirestoreListener {

    var firestoreReg: ListenerRegistration?

    func shouldReattach(for error: Error) -> Bool {
        return error.localizedDescription == "The referenced transaction has expired or is no longer valid." ||
            error.localizedDescription == "transaction closed"
    }

    func addListener() {

        let doc = Firestore.firestore().collection("foo").document("bar")
        self.firestoreReg?.remove()
        self.firestoreReg = doc.addSnapshotListener { [weak self] snapshot, error in

            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            // Catch firestore transaction expired/closed bug
            if let error = error {
                if strongSelf.shouldReattach(for: error) {
                    strongSelf.addListener()
                } else {
                    // Handle other error
                }
                return
            }

            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update - 23rd November 2017**

I've reported this as a bug to Firebase and they've acknowledged the issue. They're now working on a fix, but have not provided an ETA. Only to keep an eye on their release notes:

https://firebase.google.com/support/releases

---

I've recently started migrating my iOS Swift code from the original Firebase RTDB to the new Firestore (Beta) and I've run into a problem that never used to happen with the RTDB.

**Update:**

The error seems to be occurring randomly in all of my addSnapshotListener methods. Essentially after adding a listener, every so often it would get triggered (despite there being no changes to the database) and an error would be returned. Once this happens, the listener appears to become invalidated and no longer listens to changes.

**Error localized description:**

> The referenced transaction has expired or is no longer valid.

Googling the error message returns a few posts relating to Google Cloud Platform, but I couldn't find anything specifically for Firebase Firestore. Any help on this would be much appreciated. I've added some sample code below, but really I've seen this happen randomly in pretty much every snapshot listener method I've used throughout my app.

**Sample code:**

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("foo").document("bar").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in

    guard let snapshot = snapshot, snapshot.exists else {
        if let error = error {
            print("ERROR Reading /foo/bar with error message: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        methodB()
        return
    }

    guard let dict = snapshot.data() as? [String: String], let value = dict["key"] else {
        print("WARNING - No value for 'key' in dictionary")
        methodB()
        return
    }

    // Check database value for 'key' matches 'someValue'
    if value == "someValue" {
        print("Success, returned value matches 'someValue'")
        methodA()
    } else {
        print("WARNING - value for 'key' in dictionary does not match 'someValue'")
        methodB()
    }
}
```

And it seems like it's not just the iOS SDK that's showing this error:

[Error in onSnapshot: FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: transaction closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877243/error-in-onsnapshot-firebaseerror-code-invalid-argument-transaction-closed)

**Update**

Similar to the link above, I've also noticed a lot of my listeners randomly return with the following error message:

> ERROR: transaction closed

The Android SDK appears to be unaffected so far.

Comment: I have had a similar issue, hopefully someone responds.

Comment: Any news on that issue ? i´m still getting "Transaction Expired"...

Comment: Unfortunately no news from Firebase and I'm still (frequently) seeing the error. I've added some sample code above for the workaround I use. It's not ideal, but it's helped to ensure that my listeners haven't prematurely expired/closed.