# With firestore, is it possible to configure offline persistence to set 'off' in a specific document?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I need to set off the persistence in a certain document in Firestore; but all other documents should work with default configuration [like this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline?authuser=0#configure_offline_persistence) implementation. I have implemented the code; but calling `firestoreSettings` again causing this error in below:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseFirestore has already been
>   started and its settings can no longer be changed. You can only call
>   setFirestoreSettings() before calling any other methods on a
>   FirebaseFirestore object.
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.setFirestoreSettings(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:140)

How can I achieve to set `setPersistenceEnabled=false` for a specific document or is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires persistence to be disabled for a single document?

Comment: There is a document which is used for tracking driver's location in real-time. This document has a GeoPoint field. When driver's internet connection is offline, write operations are cached for later to sync with firestore. After the connectivity is restored and back online again, driver can send old geo-points that is irrelevant; because driver should be marked in real-time on MapView. I think that if I had a choice to choose a document to disable persistence, all those accumulated write operations won't be sent all at once.

Comment: By the way, I know that I only can send those write operations if the device has an internet connection and simply ignore to sync with firestore if device connectivity is offline. It is just a curiosity of mine that firestore could do something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk persistence can only be enabled for the entire Firestore client, before performing any other operations. It cannot be enabled/disabled for specific collections, queries or documents.

Comment: So in case we have a large DB (eg. 1 - 2GB), our web application would download the whole database to the client's device to make it available offline. This for many users might be overkilling. Are there any best practices to tackle this case other than prompt, if possible, the user whether (s)he want to have the data available offline?

Comment: Only documents that you actually read will be persisted locally, but beyond that you have no control over the disk cache.

Answer (score 1):

The way offline persistence works is by synchronizing the *current* state of each document written while offline.  It doesn't synchronize the entire history of all the writes.  The history of writes is irrelevant - what matters is only the current values in the document.  Therefore, enabling persistence is not as expensive as you might be expecting.

As Frank said, you can't selectively choose to synchronize only some documents.  It's either entirely off or on.  Personally, I don't think you have a compelling case to disable it.

Comment: Doug: in my case, I know it's not the proper use case, but I have code that needs to go into production so I'm disabling persistence as a workaround for the slow queries issue (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46828867/2344535) . Ideally, only one Activity would need the workaround. So my question is really: is there any other solution for the slow queries issue?

Comment: @doug-stevenson One case could be if I am storing some critical information (billing, payment, secret keys etc) in some collection.