# Why does Firestore sometimes not return anything, no error, nothing?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing a simple query and periodically Firestore doesn't return anything. No error, no results, nothing.

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("groupChats")
        .order(by: kUpdatedAt, descending: true)
        .whereField("memberIds", arrayContains: currentUserId)
        .limit(to: 15).getDocuments { [weak self] snapshot, error in 
             // nothing inside here ever hits
        }
```

I'm not really sure how to proceed or debug this since this seems to be inside of Firestore. The user has an internet connection. Pulling to refresh and calling that query again returns the same seeming no-op result.

Any ideas what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: Firestore has offline data features, that are probably causing your problem. For Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default. Have you checked where the data comes from using `snapshot.metadata.isFromCache`?

Comment: How are those features causing this problem though? Not entirely sure how those two things relate? As I said in my post, the block never fires so I can't actually look at `snapshot.metadata.isFromCache`

Comment: Right. I was hasty to judge the offline persistence.

Comment: Your code comment says it never hits there, how do you know it never hits ? Do you log something ? Or have a breakpoint ?

Comment: Yes, I have logs and breakpoints in the error and non-error cases and nothing prints or hits

Comment: Does this problem happen with other quires to Firestore? Or just with this particular query??

Comment: It's happened with a number of queries

Comment: Hasn't happened in the last week or so however

Comment: Okay, just happened to me after I tried to add ~900 strings to an array. No writes don't seem to work

Comment: The real answer is because beta. Firestore has been in beta for a while now and may remain beta for quite a while longer. GMail was in beta for years, if you remember.

Comment: No, that's not the real answer, unfortunately. Gmail and Firestore are very different products built by different teams at different points in time. Their only similarities are that they're offered by google and both have a beta tag on them. Firestore works well for me 99% of the time and in this 1%, something is happening where a call doesn't return. Both times have occurred around a large get or set of data, so there's at least that breadcrumb there to go off of. Would love more data from a  Firestore engineer or support rep

Comment: Are you sure it has nothing to do with limits? (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits) The sdk usage limits the payload size (for instance) to 16mb instead of 256mb. Any chance you added monitoring (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start) so you can inspect your loads?

Comment: Is your request timing out?

Comment: I don't believe so; a timeout should at least return the error closure

Comment: Have you tried logging your error or snapshot?

Comment: The completion block never returns so I can't log the error. Which makes this especially strange and tricky

Comment: Is there any reproduction path? Do you have a minimum project which reproduces this behaviour?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I just have a few team members that bring this up periodically and I’m unable

Comment: Unable to reproduce it

Comment: Well. Seems that you have ruled most of the solutions. I saw something similar to your problem a couple of months ago and was driving me crazy. It only happened sometimes and there were not even errors to track. Searching through stack overflow I found this answer, which I gave it a try, and haven't seen it happening since then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717898/firestore-slow-performance-issue-on-getting-data so probably you can try it. I know that snapshotListener is not ideal but at least it is a temporary solution until Firesbase guys fix the issue

Comment: IMHO your best shot is to enable verbose logging and try to pin down the issue
see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Firestore#enablelogging_
You can also check this with Firebase support, they usually respond within a day or two.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate indexes for the queries that doesn't behave as expected?

Comment: The issue ended up being caching was turned on by default and I had a massive cache on the device. Turning the offline caching stuff off helped this significantly

Comment: @ZackShapiro please try below my answer, don't forget to mark my answer as correct answer and to upwote if it works.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue ended up being caching is turned on by default and I had a massive cache on the device from development and migrations. Turning the offline caching off as part of the `Firestore()` initialization helped this significantly and made my app usable again.

Answer (score 0):

you should use following code

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("groupChats")
        .order(by: kUpdatedAt, descending: true)
        .whereField("memberIds", arrayContains: currentUserId)
        .limit(to: 15).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in 
if error != nil{
            print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
        } else {
            for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Faiz. There were a lot of comments above but I mentioned before that the completion block wasn't being hit at all. It wasn't returning an error or any data at all. The issue was a large cache on my device. I answered my own question that's actually the solution for my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, for me the query field was named after a reserved word. `val type:String=""` i changed the reserved to something non-reserved and the queries are working like magic.

My code was like

```
val query=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("Organizations")
            .orderBy("name")
            .whereEqualTo("type",orgType)
```

so i changed it to something more meaningful like the following.

```
val query=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("Organizations")
            .orderBy("name")
            .whereEqualTo("organizationtype",orgType)
```