# Why does this simple Firestore 'where' query take so long?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

This query is taking longer than 10 minutes to execute and I can't figure out why. In case it's a factor, I'm running it when my app loads in react native's componentDidMount method.

There are about 12k docs in the users collection, but only about 30 of which have a fetchStatus of 206. It also seems to slow down my computer and/or internet connection while it's running.

Here's the code:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').where("fetchStatus","==",206).get()
.then(querySnap => {
    console.log(querySnap.size)
})
```

EDIT:
It seems it's something to do with my React Native environment. When I run the query via a Cloud Function, via this code, it's nice and quick:

```
export const count206 = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const querySnap = await db.collection('users').where("fetchStatus","==",206).get()
        console.log(querySnap.size)
        response.send("ok")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        response.send(error.message)
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you, by any chance, disabled indexing on that `fetchStatus` field?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717898/firestore-slow-performance-issue-on-getting-data

Comment: @jubobs: a missing index should cause the query to fail on Firestore (unlike on Firebase's realtime database, where it'd download all data and filter client-side).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks. I did not know that.

Comment: @jubobs Good thought, but no I have not disabled indexing on that field.