# Can't access data base from a Firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I tried everything , I have this cloud function (that otherwise works) :

```
     exports.contentServer = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
          admin.database().ref('/list/' + "abc").once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
              console.log(snapshot.val() );
              return null;
              }).catch(function(error) {
                  console.log("Error getting document:", error);
                  return response.send(error);
              });

 });
```

or also this :

```
     admin.database().ref('/list').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        var event = snapshot.val();   
        app.tell('Result: '+event);
   });
```

and this :

```
     exports.contentServer = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {


          var db = admin.database();


            db.ref("list/abc").once("value").then(snap => {
              var store = snap.val().description;
              return store;
            }).then(() => {
              var store = snap.val().description;
              return store;
            }).then(snap => {
              var store = snap.val().description;
              return store;
            }).catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
              response.send("error occurred");
            });

 });
```

and always get back the error :

> "Could not handle the request"

Or I get error on deploy that :

```
 Each then() should return a value or throw
```

I have a collection called **list**, inside I have a document named **"abc"**.

Is there something I have to include ? something I have to setup in Firebase to make it work ? anything basic nobody write on the docs ?

Comment: You may be interested by the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**Updated**. Return the response inside `then()` as what @Renaud Tarnec pointed out.

Using realtime database

```
exports.contentServer = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
     var database = admin.database();
     database.ref('list').child('abc').once("value", snapshot => {
         const data = snapshot.val();
         return response.send(data);
     }).catch(error => {
         return response.status(500).send(error); 
     });
});
```

If you are using firestore.

```
exports.contentServer = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
     const firestore = admin.firestore();
     firestore.collection("list").doc('abc').get().then(doc => {
         console.log(doc.data());
         return response.send(doc.data());
     }).catch(error => {
         return response.status(500).send(error);
     });
});
```

Important: Don't forget to terminate the request by calling `response.redirect(), response.send(), or responses.end()` so you can avoid excessive charges from functions that run for too long

Comment: Error: could not handle the request. I have a feeling that something really strange is going on. I can not even log things anymore to the console. What could be happening here ?

Comment: Are you using spark plan? Perhaps you have reached the qouta. @condalism

Comment: I can see on the log that it loges some text, I can see that function excuted started, then I see it ended, then after a while I see Null, which means i guess he printed null in the call to DB. so my DB has a collection named list, then inside there is one document called abc, but for some reason it wouldn't find it. (your code include once() twice so I removed one of them) . it just won't read the DB from a function.

Comment: "Function execution took 11 ms, finished with status code: 200", it takes him 10 seconds to get a return from the db function and then he prints null.

Comment: Please add your db structure in your question @condalism

Comment: And by the way, are you using firestore or realtime db. You mentioned collection and document. @condalism

Comment: It's just a collection called "list", then inside many documents, one of them called "abc" (its document ID is abc), and that's it, I need to read its content.

Comment: Are you using firestore? @condalism

Comment: Yes I use firestore....Is this way for real time db ? how its done with firestore ?

Comment: Thanks it works ! but it takes 60000ms (one minute!) to finish this function, why ? Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

Comment: Firestore cold start. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717898/firestore-slow-performance-issue-on-getting-data#46750456) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! so just wait for a while to get better ? do I have to close the connection somehow ? what if I want to return a certain page after the function finish? how its being done ? thanks elbert you helped me a lot !

Comment: @condalism & @elbertrivas If I may, in the two examples above the response is sent back before the asynchronous queries are completed. You have to send the response back within the `then()`, see my answer. You will see that the Cloud Function will execute much faster than 1 minute.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Modified following the comments above explaining the OP uses Firestore and not the Realtime Database**

You should do as follows. You have to wait that the promise returned by the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) method resolves before sending back the response. For this you need to use the `then()` method, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

```
 exports.contentServer = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      admin.firestore().collection('list').doc('abc').get()
      .then(docSnapshot => {
          console.log(docSnapshot.data());
          return response.send(docSnapshot.data()); // or any other value, like return response.send( {result: "success"} );
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log("Error getting document:", error);
          return response.status(500).send(error); 
      });
});
```

As written in the comments above, I would suggest that you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: Your answer really solved the problem. thank you so much. I have low votes so I can't even upvote you, instead I wish you have the best weekend you had for a while. ;)

Comment: @condalism Happy that I could help! At the time of writing I see that you do have the necessary points to upvote my answer. Please do so if it was helpful. And I wish you a nice WE too!!

Comment: I did. btw I have a problem with your code now, a really strange problem - it will execute a function multiple times, and I can't find a solution , can you please take a look ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979565/firebase-function-is-being-executed-multiple-times