# Error in onSnapshot: FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: transaction closed

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm recursively loading a tree stored in Firestore. The tree has ~79 nodes.

Very occasionally I'm getting this error (about one in ten full-tree loads).

Edit: the code: https://github.com/karol-depka/OrYoL

Edit: the example deployed: https://oryol.karoldepka.com/tree (sorry, no plunker for now, just this)

Details below.

Firebase version in package.json: `4.5.0`

Questions:

Where can I get more info than this basic documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.FirebaseError
?

What is the source of the problem and how to fix it?

```
3VM724:27 Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: Error: transaction closed
at new FirestoreError (error.js:164)
at JsonProtoSerializer.webpackJsonp.../../../../firebase/firestore/remote/serializer.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus (serializer.js:126)
at JsonProtoSerializer.webpackJsonp.../../../../firebase/firestore/remote/serializer.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange (serializer.js:517)
at PersistentListenStream.webpackJsonp.../../../../firebase/firestore/remote/persistent_stream.js.PersistentListenStream.onMessage (persistent_stream.js:334)
at persistent_stream.js:270
at persistent_stream.js:247
at async_queue.js:81
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:392)
at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
```

The code:

```
private processNodeEvents(nestLevel: number, snapshot: any, parents, listener: DbTreeListener) {
  const serviceThis = this
  snapshot.docChanges.forEach(function(change) {
    let data = change.doc.data()
    if (change.type === 'added') {
      const parentsPath = serviceThis.nodesPath(parents)
      console.log('node: ', nestLevel, parentsPath, data);
      serviceThis.pendingListeners ++
      data.node.onSnapshot(targetNodeDoc => {
        serviceThis.pendingListeners --
        listener.onNodeAdded(
          new NodeAddEvent(parentsPath, parentsPath[parentsPath.length - 1], targetNodeDoc, targetNodeDoc.id,
            serviceThis.pendingListeners))
        console.log('target node:', nestLevel, targetNodeDoc)
        console.log('target node title:', nestLevel, targetNodeDoc.data().title)

        const subCollection = targetNodeDoc.ref.collection('subNodes')
        console.log('subColl:', subCollection)
        subCollection.onSnapshot((subSnap: QuerySnapshot) => {
          const newParents = parents.slice(0)
          newParents.push(targetNodeDoc.ref)
          serviceThis.processNodeEvents(nestLevel + 1, subSnap, newParents, listener)
        })
      })
      // console.log('root node ref: ', targetNode);
    }
    if (change.type === 'modified') {
      console.log('Modified city: ', data);
    }
    if (change.type === 'removed') {
      console.log('Removed city: ', data);
    }
  })
}
```

Edit: another error discovered, by running the code multiple times:

```
VM3343:27 Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: Error: The referenced transaction has expired or is no longer valid.
at new FirestoreError (error.js:164)
at JsonProtoSerializer.webpackJsonp.../../../../firebase/firestore/remote/serializer.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus (serializer.js:126)
at JsonProtoSerializer.webpackJsonp.../../../../firebase/firestore/remote/serializer.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange (serializer.js:517)
at PersistentListenStream.webpackJsonp.../../../../firebase/firestore/remote/persistent_stream.js.PersistentListenStream.onMessage (persistent_stream.js:334)
at persistent_stream.js:270
at persistent_stream.js:247
at async_queue.js:81
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:392)
at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
window.console.error @ VM3343:27
```

Edit: update firebase to `4.6.0`, problem happened 3 times:

```
Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: Error: transaction closed
  at new FirestoreError (error.js:149)
  at JsonProtoSerializer.webpackJsonp.../../../../@firebase/firestore/dist/esm/src/remote/serializer.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus (serializer.js:93)
  at JsonProtoSerializer.webpackJsonp.../../../../@firebase/firestore/dist/esm/src/remote/serializer.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange (serializer.js:536)
  at PersistentListenStream.webpackJsonp.../../../../@firebase/firestore/dist/esm/src/remote/persistent_stream.js.PersistentListenStream.onMessage (persistent_stream.js:309)
  at persistent_stream.js:246
  at persistent_stream.js:222
  at async_queue.js:62
  at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:392)
  at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
  at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
```

Edit: even if the error happens, the tree seems to continue loading.

Edit: another version of the error, with `code=aborted` (after upgrading `firebase` to `4.6.0`):

```
Error in onSnapshot: FirebaseError: [code=aborted]: The referenced transaction has expired or is no longer valid.
/vendor.bundle.js:18588 errHandler()
/vendor.bundle.js:33367
/polyfills.bundle.js:2970 ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask()
/vendor.bundle.js:107276 Object.onInvokeTask()
/polyfills.bundle.js:2969 ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask()
/polyfills.bundle.js:2737 Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask()
/polyfills.bundle.js:3044 webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask()
/polyfills.bundle.js:3033 ZoneTask.invoke()
```

Comment: I've had similar problems with the iOS SDK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46710371/firebase-firestore-ios-document-snapshot-listener-error-the-referenced-trans

Comment: any news on this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I have more or less the same and it is random when it works and don't. I don't use snapshot, but valueChanges

```
ERROR Error: transaction closed
at new FirestoreError (error.js:149)
at JsonProtoSerializer.webpackJsonp.../../../../@firebase/firestore/dist/esm/src/remote/serializer.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus (serializer.js:93)
at JsonProtoSerializer.webpackJsonp.../../../../@firebase/firestore/dist/esm/src/remote/serializer.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange (serializer.js:536)
at PersistentListenStream.webpackJsonp.../../../../@firebase/firestore/dist/esm/src/remote/persistent_stream.js.PersistentListenStream.onMessage (persistent_stream.js:309)
at persistent_stream.js:246
at persistent_stream.js:222
at async_queue.js:62
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:392)
at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
```

For me it's this peace of code that provokes the error:

```
return Observable.forkJoin(entries.map(entry => {
  return this.getPick(entry)
}))
```

each entry in entries is used to return a single pick from firestore.

```
  private getPick(entryId: number) {
     return this.afs.collection<Pick>('entry/' + entryId + '/event/' + '9/' + 'picks', ref => ref.where('is_captain','==',true))
     .valueChanges()
```

I don't mean to hijack your thread, but I feel this is very relevant. If I change the forkJoin to

```
Observable.forkJoin(entries.slice(0,20)...
```

then it works, so I guess it is some kind of overload of queries.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your observations. Whenever we have new findings, let's exchange observations. For now I'm ignoring the error and things seem to work fine. Except maybe in one case the last one/few tree nodes got added several seconds after "everything was apparently done loading", but I'm not sure. Will keep my eyes open. Hopefully some Firebase staff member will comment/reply, like Frank Van Puffeln, to shed some light...

Comment: Yes, angularfire2, and I made the project a couple of days ago, so versions should be latest. This breaks my application completely, cause I need to be able to send multiple queries at a time, so I guess I will go back to MongoDB or so.

Comment: I have 3 scenarios every time I reload the app, it either:
1. Works
2. Transaction closed error
3. Takes 1-2 min and works

Comment: Thanks for the info. For me it seems to work all the time, despite the errors.
Could you try the "core" firebase sdk, instead of AngularFire? Maybe AngularFire treats those errors too seriously and decides to fail-fast, whereas the "core" firestore does not decide to fail-fast? If you go to Mongo, will you have real time notifications?